# How to use dictionary key value pairs as inputs into pyspark function?

Tags: list, dictionary, pyspark, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to define a set of arguments for a pyspark function I've written that requires the parameters listed below. Many of the parameters are consistent excluding id and date. For each animal_id, I have a list of files:
i.e.

```
database = 'animal_db' #consistent
animal_type = 'mammal' #consistent

ARGUMENTS = [(database, animal_type, animal_id, date) for date in DATE_SET]

DATE_SET = {'lion235': {'animal_db/mammal/lion/2023002/1424/12.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022013/4231/82.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022098/1421/44.csv'}, 

'kangaroo441': {'animal_db/mammal/kangaroo/2023041/1599/97.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/kangaroo/2022100/9583/14.csv'}}
```

This is the function that the arguments above feed into which is then used for another function.

```
def create_animal_table(ARGUMENTS):
  database = ARGUMENTS[0]
  animal_type = ARGUMENTS[1]
  id = ARGUMENTS[2]
  files = ARGUMENTS[4]
  log = []
  return log
```

For each id like 'lion235' I'd like a list of the filenames to feed into the files argument, i.e.
id = 'lion235'
files = ['animal_db/mammal/lion/2023002/1424/12.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022013/4231/82.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022098/1421/44.csv']

Initially I tried defining the files in the DATE_SET as a list but receive the error 'unhashable type list' so I tried a set in a dictionary, planning to convert the set to a list, but that doesn't work either. I'm not sure what this attempt to pass key value pairs into the pyspark function is called which made researching the method more complicated.

DATE_SET = {'lion235': {'animal_db/mammal/lion/2023002/1424/12.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022013/4231/82.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/lion/2022098/1421/44.csv'},

'kangaroo441': {'animal_db/mammal/kangaroo/2023041/1599/97.csv', 'animal_db/mammal/kangaroo/2022100/9583/14.csv'}}

Thank you in advance for your help!